# Angular and Asp.Net WebAPI doesnt Communicate over local network

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-webapi, devops

My **Asp.Net WebAPI** running at **192.168.1.34:454546**  and **Angular** running at **192.168.1.34:4200**
when I run **Angular** on **my pc(192.168.1.34)** app works well but **when i switch to another pc(for example:192.168.1.35)** i can access to  individuall both asp.Net WebAPI and Angular. But on page i cant see any Api data.
How can i solve this?
by the way I use Conveyor by Keyoti

Comment: Did you use the the option --host 0.0.0.0 to run your Angular application ?

Comment: Yes I did 
 I run this code `ng serve --open --host 0.0.0.0 --disable-host-check`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was my ISS service. I just enabled it from windows features. and it worked fine